# Showing a complex integral has zero real part

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to show that $\int_{\varphi}^{\space} \bar{z} \space dz $ has zero real part, for all smooth closed paths $\varphi$.

I've tested this with the example $\int_{C(0;1)}^{\space} \bar{z} \space dz $ (the disc centered around 0 with radius 1) and I get $2\pi i$. I can also prove that the real part is zero for all $\varphi$ being a disc.

A hand wavey proof might be to say that all closed paths may be represented as the union of discs... maybe?

I think a better approach might be to write $\varphi = u + iv$ and express $Re(\int_{\varphi}^{\space}  \bar{z} \space dz)$ as a real integral, as someone suggested to me but I'm not 100% sure how exactly to do this.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Another hand wavey approach is to note that the real part of the integral shouldn't care about the imaginary part of the integrand. Therefore you _should_ get the same result as you would when integrating $z$.

Comment: So we integrate the entire function, and then integrate just the imaginary, and show that they are equal?? Could you show how this might be achieved. My main problem is representing one part (real/imaginary) of the function when integrating. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Re(\int_{\varphi}^{\space}  \bar{z} \space dz)=Re(\int_{\varphi} \overline{\varphi_1 (t) +i\varphi_2 (t)} (\varphi_1' (t) +i\varphi_2' (t)) dt =\int_{\varphi}( \varphi_1  (t)\varphi_1' (t) +\varphi_2 (t) \varphi_2' (t)) dt =\frac{\varphi_1^2 (t) +\varphi_2^2 (t) }{2}|_{t_0}^{t_0} =0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Why do we have $t_0$ and $t_0$ instead of some arbitrary $c$ and $d$ if we are looking at all closed paths?

Comment: Oh, because it's closed, of course sorry!